# Dismiss multiple modal views with several navigation controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

Try and follow me through the image below here. **ViewController A** is pushing **navController A** modally, which in turn shows **ViewController A** through **ViewController F** as show segues. The reason for this is that I need a `UINavigationBar` in order to go back and forth between the different `UIViewControllers`. But at one point in this interaction line you can actually push up another navigation interaction line, from **ViewController B** to **navController B**. They will both eventually end up at **ViewController F**, but with slightly different data. When I reach **ViewController F** and I'm all done with that `UIViewController`, I'd like to return to **ViewController A** instantly, without seeing multiple dismiss animations.

To do this I've used wide range of different lines of code, but they all end up with the same issue. I can get them to dismiss fine, so I end up at **ViewController A**. But when I've used the interaction line using **navController B** it will animate the dismissal of **ViewController F**, but there will still be a **ViewController F** behind that dismissal, and when the animation is done it flickers away and I end up at **ViewController A**. Basically it looks like there is another **ViewController F** behind the one I'm dismissing, but there isn't (I've checked in the 3D View in Xcode).

I can't seem to fix it. I tried removing **navController B** and it works fine, I only see 1 animation and end up at **ViewController A** without the issue explained above, but I have to have that **navController B** there. Simply put there seems to be an issue when using several `UINavigationControllers` with modal views.

Code to dismiss: `ViewControllerA.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)`
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I finally ended up doing was to check wether the `PresentingViewController` at **ViewController F** was **ViewController A** or not since if you went through ViewController G the `PresentingViewController` would be **ViewController B.** And in **ViewController F** I first dismissed the front modal presentation without animation and then the second one with animation. It looks okay.

```
if let _ = presentingViewController as? ViewControllerA {
  view.window?.rootViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

} else {
  dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
  view.window?.rootViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

The `view.window?.rootViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` will start dismissing all the modals form the very `rootViewController`. Just adding two `dismissViewControllerAnimated()` after each other in the `else`-clause will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to avoid presenting modal view on a modal view. Consider pushing View Controller G from the View Controller B to the same navigation flow, rather then presenting it modally. This would allow you to always dismiss only one navigation flow of the NavController A.

Comment: Yeah, well according to our designers that is not an option right now. So I kind of have to fix this.